# Travelling through a black hole like through a wormhole?

Tags: space, black-holes, universe, wormholes

To add to my previous question. Can a black hole be a wormhole or can a wormhole exist within a black hole? The result I want to get is this:

- *You enter a black hole in one part of space and exit from a white hole in a very different part of space. So you travel through space and time across the universe.*

If somebody knows or has any idea of how this could be explained and could work theoretically or better scientifically, please aid me.

Edit: I've noticed in cosmos adventures authors use some kind of vortexes to travel extremely large distances between galaxies. What is this vertex? I couldn't find information about it.

Comment: What's a white hole? Is there any evidence that such white holes exist? The problem with using black holes as entry portals is that _from the point of view of an external observer_ it takes an infinitely long time for an object to fall into one; so that from the point of view of the plot travelling through a black hole would immediately end the book (or at least end the participation of that character).

Comment: I bet this is what Einstein actually have in mind when he mentioned his biggest blunder...

Comment: This is a very well established concept in science fiction. I like the white hole part though (which I haven't encountered before in such a context) because it sounds like a fun concept. In our actual universe, we have not found such a wormhole yet so we don't know anything, but strictly speaking AlexP is of course right: One cannot really enter a black hole outside of science fiction.

Comment: @AlexP What's a white hole, indeed! A hypothetical counterpart to a black hole. Theorized about in the 1970s, and assumed to be at the other end of a black hole, but somewhere else in the cosmos. Possibly if white holes exist they may be indistinguishable from black holes. The concept has fallen out of fashion.

Comment: @user6760 You lose. Einstein's biggest blunder was the cosmological constant. Just go and look it up. It will do you the world of good.

Comment: @a4android: I was trying to be fu... oh nvm.

Comment: @user6760 Of course! I was playing with the gag, but bringing it back to reality.

Comment: I think you probably mean "vortex", not "vertex."

Comment: You do realize when entering a black hole any object in the universe is destroyed by gravity sheer? Basically as molecules in your front gets closer to the black hole and deeper in the gravity well they becomes affected more by the gravity so that they are ripped away from you. It basically turns you into soup, then loose atoms, then smashes those into its infinite nothingness.

Comment: @Braydon oh, that's obviously bad. How to prevent that?

Comment: Umm. . . I mean you don't, you just die. There is no known force in the universe that is close to being able to counteract a black hole.

Comment: As mentioned earlier in the comment, google up "white hole", then "wormhole". Please do your research first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can a black hole be a wormhole or can a wormhole exist within a black
>   hole?

No. A black hole cannot be a wormhole. But, yes, a wormhole might exist inside a black hole. The "might" part results from the fact that our understanding of black holes is theoretical. There's nothing wrong with a good theoretical understanding, but it helps if it can be validated empirically.

The most likely candidate for a black hole with a wormhole in its interior is the so-called Kerr black hole.

> A Kerr black hole is a type of black hole that possesses only mass
>   and angular momentum (but not electrical charge – the third possible
>   property of a black hole). In other words, a Kerr black hole is an
>   uncharged black hole that rotates about a central axis. It is named
>   after the New Zealand mathematician Roy Kerr who, in 1963, became the
>   first person to solve the field equations of Einstein's general theory
>   of relativity for a situation of this kind.
>
> Kerr black holes are probably the commonest in nature, since the
>   massive stars from which they typically form possess rotation (but no
>   overall charge) before they collapse at the end of their lives. By the
>   principle of conservation of angular momentum, much of this spin is
>   then retained by the black hole following the star's terminal
>   collapse.
>
> A Kerr black hole has the following distinct regions:
>
> ring singularity inner and outer event horizons ergosphere static
>   limit (the boundary between the ergosphere and normal space)
>
> Inside a Kerr black hole
>
> At each event horizon the roles of space and time are reversed; so, in
>   the case of a Kerr black hole space and time swap places twice. The
>   singularity is ring-shaped and, except if approached on its equatorial
>   plane, is repulsive. This fact is simply the result of the equations
>   of Kerr's metrical geometry. The singularity is also a temporal one,
>   so that it can be avoided. In theory, it is possible to escape from a
>   black hole, although not by the same way you went in. On leaving the
>   black hole you would find yourself either in a region of "negative
>   space," the physical meaning of which is unclear, or in an entirely
>   different universe.

However, they do come with a hazard warning. Enter them at your peril. However, for the purposes of a science-fiction story they can be assumed to be safe enough for your characters to travel them unmolested. This, of course, is pure hand-waving necessary for the story's sake.

> Everything that has been said here is purely theoretical. The Kerr
>   solution is very unstable, corresponding as it does to a black hole in
>   complete isolation. The addition of extraneous matter, such as even
>   the approach of a would-be traveler, could be enough to destabilize
>   the Kerr solution and make travel through the black hole unrealistic.
>   To properly investigate the feasibility of journeys past or through
>   the singularities of black holes we need to be able to take quantum
>   effects into account. However, this will require a quantum theory of
>   gravity – one of the chief goals of contemporary theoretical physics.

Source: [Kerr black hole](http://www.daviddarling.info/encyclopedia/K/Kerr_black_hole.html)

Answer (score 0):

Wormhole in blackhole. ...you might need to spend some time binge-watching Austin's SCIENCE! Series on Game Theory.

Here's how i explained blackholes to my mother. Picture a banana, the yellow skin (the part that you peel away to get to the white stuff) is the actual blackhole as we know it. Light cannot leave the skin hence the "black" part.

The skin *does not kill you.* the meat does. What the "meat" of blackholes various from instance to instance but usually it is made of HYPER DENSE STAR(S) thus inflicting HUGE amounts of mass and energy upon the space-time fabric-rug thing that we perceive as reality.

The skin of the blackhole is merely the threshold or event horizon of the actual thing that kills you with stupid amounts of gravity that is generated by the "white star" within. So in otherwords blackhole is a misnomier and there is no exit or escape unless we're talking about 6+ dimensional movement or magic/dues ex machina.

https://m.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLOl4b517qn8hmH4Pe0_P8-Y723NmtL08S <- that is the playlist of Austin's The SCIENCE series. I suggest you watch that because of random unanswered questions.

Oh and wormholes? Watch the Portal Science Episode.

TL:DR

Instant death by hyper gravity inside black hole

Wormhole: large scale nuclear fusion and space-time compression. Not good for any lifeform existing within 3 dimensions regardless of Carbon based or other element.

Good try. Might need to add intervening 5+ dimensional species/entities for wormhole/blackhole-whitehole/wormhole in blackhole based travel.